# How can I select between multiple audio tracks, using RenderFile for my Filtergraph construction?

Tags: c#, .net, directshow, directshow.net

I'm developing an application in C# and I'm using DirectShow.NET libraries to render .AVI files with multiple audio tracks

How can I switch between multiple audio tracks ? I'm using RenderFile to build my filtergraph rather than manually build it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should switching between audio tracks be supported, one of the filters in the pipeline (demultiplexing filter) would expose [`IAMStreamSelect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319793%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface and you can use it to switch tracks.

> The `IAMStreamSelect` interface selects from the available streams on a
>   parser filter. For example, a file might contain audio streams encoded
>   in several languages, such as English, German, and French. The
>   application could use this interface to select which language is
>   played.

You can use `ICaptureGraphBuilder2::FindInterface` method to quickly locate the interface in your filter graph.

Comment: I found the Morgan Stream Switcher filter which exposed IAMStreamSelect and started using it. Thanks for your help !